# How do you let specific people do commands

Tags: node.js, command, discord.js

I am making a discord.js bot and I have a problem.
I want to make it so I have to allow who can use my commands. So if I wanted only one person who gets a private command I can just add code and only they can use it. I do not want to make a specific role for them because I want them to be able to use it in any discord server. Can anyone help me out?

Well ive searched up what to do but people only say stuff to do with roles.

I currently have no code since I have no suggestions yet.

I have no expectations for what any errors could be because I dont really know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict access to commands not only based on roles, but through user IDs as well. Each user has a unique ID linked to them in Discord. When a message is sent, you can check the author's ID against those that are allowed to use the commands.

In order to store the IDs, you can use a json file or database. For the purpose of keeping it simple, I've used a json file for this example.

Example `permitted.json`:

```js
[
  "189855563893571595",
  "581635015151058944",
  "135190099439779841"
]
```

Example message event:

```js
const permitted = require('./permitted.json'); // path may vary depending on the file location

client.on('message', message => {
  if (!permitted.includes(message.author.id)) return;

  // continue on 
});
```

Example "access" command:

```js
// permitted = required json file
// args[1] = ID argument

const fs = require('fs');

if (message.author.id !== 'yourID') return;

let action;

if (!permitted.includes(args[1])) {
  permitted.push(args[1]);
  action = 'added to';
} else {
  permitted.splice(permitted.indexOf(args[1]), 1);
  action = 'removed from';
}

try {
  fs.writeFileSync('./permitted.json', JSON.stringify(permitted));
  message.channel.send(`That user has been ${action} the permitted list.`);
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```